# Complex MySql joins - rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

So, I have the models User, Submission, and Download. A User can have many submissions, and a Submission has many downloads. A download tracks the IP address etc, and is structured as time series data. The problem is, I need to be able to do a query like finding the user with the most amount of downloads in the past week. I'm really not sure where to start with this, and any help would be appreciated.

The main parts of the tables include the User which has an `id`, Submission which has a `user_id` and `id`, and Download which has `submission_id` and `id`.

So basically, I need to select all the downloads for submissions that are owned by a specific user, count them up, and then sort them to find the user that has the most downloads. Is this really possible, or efficient? Should I just add a say `owner_id` to the Download model, and then query based on that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I dont have 50 reputation so I cant add a comment on you raw sql answer but you can try this to write in rails query this:

```
User.all.joins(:submission => :downloads).group(:user_id).order("count(user_id) DESC")
```

So get all user, joins submission table by user_id and get its downloads association table as well, then group by user_id...etc

Give that a try?

Comment: Hey this works! (for the most part) final query was: ```User.all.joins(:submissions => :downloads).group("users.id").order("count(users.id) DESC")``` Any idea how I could go about getting the download count with the user? In my raw query, it returns say ```568;199, 556;195``` (user_id, count). Thanks by the way!

Comment: I seem to have figured it out by adding ```.count``` to the end of the query, and it mapped the user id to the # of downloads. This should work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to Rails but I think you should use

```
has_many :downloads, :through => :submission
```

on your user model. Then I think you can do something like `User.downloads.count`

Comment: This could work, except that I need to be able to sort it for all the users and find the users with the top downloads count. I don't think sorting like that would be very efficient. I think I've found a solution though with raw sql, and might post in a bit.

Comment: Ordering isn't a problem - you can order by `count_rails-magic` (sorry I can't remember what rails will put there). Raw sql shouldn't be a problem at all though and I'm guessing it'll be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Submission.joins(:user,:downloads).
group('submissions.id','downloads.submission_id').
order('count_all DESC').
limit(10).
count
```

You'll figure it out.

There are other joins you might wanna try out, but this is an easy starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Why don' you try this Download.all.group(:user_id).order("count(id) DESC" )

So you get all the Downloads, group them by user_id and count all the downloads for that user and order by DESC.

I think that's what you want?

*by the way don't forget to add the user_id column.

Comment: This is what I was planning on doing if I couldn't find another solution using joins. I didn't really want to add another column, but I think I've found a solution that will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up solving the issue with a raw sql query, and this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    COUNT(*) AS subdownload_count
FROM users
    INNER JOIN submissions ON users.id = submissions.creator_id
    INNER JOIN downloads ON submissions.id = downloads.submission_id
GROUP BY 
    users.id
ORDER BY
    subdownload_count DESC
```

I've been using nosql a lot the past year, so I don't completely understand joins in rails, but I'll probably figure out how to implement this soon. Thanks to anyone who commented!

Comment: But then you'll be writing SQL :-P

Comment: Yeah I know :( I'm going to try to figure out how to work this into a rails query using active record, other wise this works just the same.